# Ruby: register output from a shell command

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, command-line

I have a shell command, that I run from ruby:

```
 cat_command = "cat 0.mpg 7.mpg 15.mpg 8.mpg 1.mpg > intermed.mpg"  

 %x[cd #{my_dir} && #{cat_command}]
```

It returns

```
cat: 8.mpg: No such file or directory
```

How do I catch this response (for rescuing/ error handling). In ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually figured it out..

```
 stderr = Open3.popen3("cat 0.mpg 7.mpg 15.mpg 8.mpg 1.mpg > intermed.mpg" )
 stderr[2].gets
  => "cat: 0.mpg: No such file or directory\n"
```